# Symfony FOSRestController as a service (Dependency injection)

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to use dependency injection in my controller. I'm using FOSRestController.

I received an error :

> Bundle "app.person_rest_controller" does not exist or it is not
>   enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of
>   your AppKernel.php file? in
>   /var/www/html/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml (which is
>   being imported from "/var/www/html/app/config/routing.yml").

My Controller looks like :

```
class PersonRestController extends FOSRestController
{

    private $entityManager;
    private $container;
    private $sendNewContactRabbitMQProducer;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, $container, Producer $rabbitMQProducer)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->sendNewContactRabbitMQProducer = $rabbitMQProducer;
    }

    public function postPersonAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
    {
        ...
    }
```

My routing.yml :

```
service_person:
    type: rest
    prefix: /v1
    resource: "@app.person_rest_controller"
    name_prefix:  api_1_ # naming collision
```

And my services.yml :

```
services:
    app.person_rest_controller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\PersonRestController
        arguments:
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            - "@service_container"
            - "@person.rabbitmq.producer.send_new_contact"
    person.rabbitmq.producer.send_new_contact:
        class: AppBundle\Service\SendNewContactRabbitMQProducer
        arguments: []
        calls:
            - [setRabbitMQProducer, ["@old_sound_rabbit_mq.send_person_id_from_hotelpro4u_producer"]]
            - [setLogger, ['@logger']]
```

I base my work on this : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/990

An idea ?

Thank you ! =)

Comment: Note: never inject the whole container to a service, but just the services etc. you really need and want to use. That'll increase your testability and so on. If you need to inject to much dependencies, your service is to large.

Comment: Thanks for that note, I will consider that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the solution, it's was a stupid error :

The service controller don't have a @ before the name.

Change :

```
service_person:
    type: rest
    prefix: /v1
    resource: "@app.person_rest_controller"
    name_prefix:  api_1_ # naming collision
```

to this :

```
service_person:
    type: rest
    prefix: /v1
    resource: "app.person_rest_controller"
    name_prefix:  api_1_ # naming collision
```

Answer (score 0):

Two quick things, especially since you seem to have an error message that actually helps you:

1. You need to install the FosRESTBundle via composer
2. You need to enable it in you AppKernel.php

Both of these are explained on the [official Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/1-setting_up_the_bundle.html).
Generally, you find the AppKernel.php under `/symfony/project/root/doc/app/AppKernel.php`